# Websocket NodeJS lite (no fallback)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm currently working with nodeJS and Socket.IO. But the problem is : i having a website who  only support recent browsers and so, websockets. I really don't need a 400kb client.js.

My question is easy : is there a nodeJS module who work only with websocket ? no fallback for old browsers, no ajax fallback etc... ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Socket.io ultimately depends on the [ws](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ws) module to make WebSocket connections.

You can use this module on the server side in combination with the raw [WebSocket client-side API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket).  Note that in addition to losing fallback support, you also lose socket.io's automatic reconnection feature.

Also consider that it's not just the actual browser you have support.  Many people are behind firewalls/proxies that don't support or actively block WebSocket connections.  So even though the browser supports the API, your user will still be unable to use your app.  For this reason, you may want to consider keeping Socket.io anyway.

BTW, the [client code](https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.4.js) is only 20 kB gzipped, not 400.

Comment: Oh, i didn't know websocket can be off if behind firewall or proxy !

Thank you for your complete answer !

PS : Yes it's not 400, do you know the french expression "Talk like a Marseillais" ? xD :)